# FETCH AWS KMS asymmetric keys - JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms, encryption-asymmetric

I need to fetch AWS KMS asymmetric keys from my java code. Plus is there a way I can upload any outside key to kms and fetch that through java code?

Please let me know if you have any suggestion or solution for this.